# How to remove in jquery a table column in case two cell have same value

Tags: html, jquery

I have this situation

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val 1 | val 2 | val 3 | val 4 | val 3 |

as you can see col 3 and 5 have the same value.

In this case how can I check the values and see if are the same and then hide col 3 giving the following result?

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 4 | Col 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val 1 | val 2 | val 4 | val 3 |

it's been 2 days I'm trying this without any success. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by the requirement in "column 3" there are two cells "col 3, val3" these are not the same as column 5's "col 5, val 3" - if you remove the whole column, you remove the whole column - do all the rows for the two matching columns need to match? (as in, they *don't* in your own example).   Is there only ever one row or is it per-row? Do you mean "clear" rather than remove?  If you remove col3's val3 then col3 will have val4  and col5 will be empty - is that intended?     Why remove col 3 and not col 5?

Comment: substantially if column 3 and column 5 have the same value then column 3 have to disappear regardless of the other rows. those are the requirements i've been asked for. i know, it's weird.

Comment: So, only col3 and col5?  What if col2 and col4 are the same?  Or col1 and col3 - would it be col3 that goes in that case? or col1?   Pretty sure you've been given an example rather than a requirement.

Comment: And which part are you stuck on?  Finding duplicate values in a row?   Removing (or is it "hiding"?) a single cell / a whole column?

Comment: this is all about col 3 and 5. other rows/column dont matter. as long col 3 and 5 have the same value col 3 have to be removed or hidden (is the same)

Comment: `$("table").find("tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)").hide()`

Comment: im stuck on the whole code. i have no clue where to start even tho i tried few things that came to my mind

Comment: $("table").find("tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)").hide() ... it works at half... i mean it moves the other fields, this should not happen

Comment: deeply sorry if im not very clear, really i am. tyring to do my best. thanks for your patience. 

i've updated the question. 
basically jquery should check the value of col 3 and if is the same of col 5 then remove (or hide, is the same) the entire col 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get specific column values using:

```
$("tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(2)").text()
```

Note that `:eq` is 0-based so this is 2nd row, 3rd column.   This assumes your th's are in your thead (original html wasn't provided).

You can then access an entire column using

```
td:nth-child(3)
```

note that `:nth-child` is 1-based (to match css nth-child... helpful...)

If your `th`'s are in your `thead` then you'll need an additional selector for the same `thead>th:nth-child(3)`

Put together:

```js
// Check if row 1, col3 = row 1, col5

var cell1x3 = $("table>tbody>tr:eq(0)>td:eq(2)").text();
var cell1x5 = $("table>tbody>tr:eq(0)>td:eq(4)").text();

console.log(cell1x3, cell1x5)
if (cell1x3 == cell1x5)
{
    console.log("match")
    
    // remove entire column, including th
    $("table th:nth-child(3),table td:nth-child(3)").remove();
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th { background-color: #CCC }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1</td>
      <td>Val 2</td>
      <td>Val 3</td>
      <td>Val 4</td>
      <td>Val 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to unique the data then only output it

```
let unique = [...new Set(myArray)]
```

Comment: unfortunately i cant work on the data, i can work only at the rendered table